# Calculating the angle where the surface of a circle can "see" the surface of another adjacent circle.

Tags: geometry

I saw a question asking "If the Moon was moved to the surface of the Earth, from how far away on the Earth's surface would it be visible?".  (The question says to ignore any other factors like gravity making it smash into the Earth's surface and effectively destroying both bodies).

Basically, it's this, I think:

[image]

We know AB, which is the radius of the Earth, and we know CD, which is the radius of the Moon.  AC is the sum of these two.  Even though it doesn't really look like it in my sketch, I think that the lines CD and AB are parallel, and that ABE and CDE are both right-angle triangles.

We need to work out the angle at A, which we can use as a ratio of the circumference of the Earth (which obviously is another known quantity), to work out the distance around the circle to B.

Are my assumptions correct?  Is it possible, from those givens, to calculate the angle at A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to the radius $AB$. Call the point of intersection $F$.
[image]

Triangle $\triangle AFC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $F$.
We have

\begin{align}
\lvert AC\rvert &= \lvert AB\rvert + \lvert CD\rvert, \\
\lvert AF\rvert &= \lvert AB\rvert - \lvert CD\rvert, \\
\end{align}

and
$$ \lvert \angle A \rvert = \lvert \angle CAF \rvert
 = \arccos\left(\frac{\lvert AF\rvert}{\lvert AC\rvert}\right). $$